# Updating paramenter issue via sed

Tags: linux, bash, sh, rhel7

In my bash script. I have as below

```
 HOST_IP=`hostname -I`

 sed -i -e "/dirParam\.dprop_web_service_host=/ s/=.*/=http://$HOST_IP:9001/datasources/$INSTANCE" -e "s/\r$//" $SCB_ORDM/dir.properties
```

Before:
directorParam.dprop_web_service_host=http://localhost:9001

While execute the above script. I get error message

> sed: -e expression #1, char 50: unknown option to `s'

I am expecting:
directorParam.dprop_web_service_host=http://10.10.405.30:9001

Comment: You need to escape the literal `/`'s in your `sed` command, or change the delimiters... it can't figure out what is what (and neither can anyone else probably). And `sed` might not even be necessary, bash parameter substitution would probably work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the next character after `s` (substitute command) is `/` so it is the delimiter it must be escaped in pattern and replace string

```
 sed -i -e "/dirParam\.dprop_web_service_host=/ s/=.*/=http:\/\/$HOST_IP:9001\/datasources\/$INSTANCE/" -e "s/\r$//" $SCB_ORDM/dir.properties
```

otherwise another delimiter can be used

```
 sed -i -e "/dirParam\.dprop_web_service_host=/ s@=.*@=http://$HOST_IP:9001/datasources/$INSTANCE@" -e "s/\r$//" $SCB_ORDM/dir.properties
```

Comment: I get space between IP and port  :(. I used the second option